# How to break area chart in excel

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I've been trying to create a separated "broken" area chart.
The top chart is the desired outcome and the table attached is the data populating it.

Do you know what is the best way to achieve the desired result?
[[image: data][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4XrS.png)

[image: top table is the desired outcome]

thanks alot !

Comment: Try the following: Add a column for the gaps (use "`1`" where the gaps are), then use a combo chart with 100% stacked columns and colour the bars for the gaps white.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra row between your areas.

[image: Rows with 2 blank spaces between areas.]